# Add icon to MenuItem vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I use MainMenu and ContextMenu, MenuStrip and ContextMenuStrip not looking like Windows 7, I use Windows 7.

[image: MainMenu menuitem]

[image: MenuItem with icon]

How to add icon?, add icon only, no change the menuitem style, only add icon.

---

MenuItem with icon:
[image: MenuItem with icon]
MenuItem with icon and style changed:
[image: Menuitem with icon(Changed style)]

Comment: Examine the properties for a menu item.

Comment: Use the `MenuItem.OwnerDraw` property.  There are examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.menuitem.ownerdraw(v=vs.100).aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5461/Working-with-OwnerDraw-Menus-in-VB-NET).

Answer (score 2):

```
RightClick MenuItem --> goto Properties --> 
choose Image option --> Click Add button --> import user image
```

Comment: this is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Mainmenu is obsolete, if you think use obsolete controls for appearance reasons, you can't. Icons on MainMenu is only with a draw attribute, but it changes the normal appearance with Windows Old one.

The appearance is not the most important in a program, if you like the Windows 7 controls and icons

Comment: Some programs can add icons to menu without altering the Windows 7 appearance